# Android layer-list : bitmap issue with app:srcCompat

Tags: android, bitmap, android-studio-2.3

After updating to Studio 2.3 when i tried to create a layer list with a vector drawable it prompt to use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src` in `bitmap`.

can any one help me to add `vector drawable to layer list` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite" />

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login">
    </bitmap>

</item>

</layer-list>
```

Already added

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No. nothing so far

Comment: ok. I'm going to try something. let me know if you come across something as well.

Comment: I'm having exact same problem. Still no joy with this?

Comment: reported as bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123822220

Answer (score 22):

I found a solution for your problem

Modify second item to this:

```
<item android:gravity="center" android:drawable="@drawable/login"/>
```

**UPDATE**

this will cause crash on API < 21. There is not any better way.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution that doesn't make the app crash for API < 21?

Comment: on some Android versions vector drawable looks ugly (becomes distorted)

Comment: @user25 Can you say which devices? Or which Api versions?

Comment: You can add a png for API < 21 this will lead to distorted images though, but it doesnt crash anymore, by now you might considering rasing the minSDK to 21 (targeting 85% of Android phones as of now)

Answer (score 6):

I managed to do it the following way:

```
<item
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawable="@drawable/login" />
```

Comment: error: attribute drawable (aka app.name:drawable) not found

Answer (score -4):

Instead of doing :

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login">
    </bitmap>
</item>
```

You need to declare the background as follow:

```
<item
    android:gravity="center"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/login"/>
```

Also, make sure that the element `app schema` is presented:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    ....
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I think `<item> android:gravity="center" app:srcCompat="@drawable/login" </item>` is not valid, did you mean `<item android:gravity="center" app:srcCompat="@drawable/login"> </item>`?

Comment: this solution did not work for me for whatever reason. Crashes with: `<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable`

Comment: What a random answer! @JoseF Did you even test that yourself?

Comment: @JoseF well... `app:srcCompat="@drawable/login"` will never work, it's only for `ImageView`

Comment: but we can just use `android:drawable="@drawable/login"` in `item` (it even works for vector drawables)